# How to use WP-reCAPTCHA on a form

Tags: plugins

I have a Wordpress 3.5.1 powered website that has the plugin WP-reCAPTCHA installed. This plugin places a reCAPTCHA field at the bottom of the comments form of my website.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to use this plugin on a template page that I've created, outside of the comments form.

If I download the stand alone reCAPTCHA code, and try to use that, it throws fatal errors because the same library is already loaded, via the WP plugin.

I'm hoping that someone will be able to help me out!

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

That plugin is only for comment, registration and email spam protection.

You need a plugin like [reCAPTCHA Form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recaptcha-form/) if you want to create contact forms protected by the reCAPTCHA system.